# Metafor Package: How to conduct Meta Regression with reliability generalization

Tags: mixed-model, reliability, meta-regression, cronbachs-alpha, generalization

How to conduct meta regression in "metafor" after I got I2 heterogenity 94%. My study reliability generalization alpha Cronbach, with continuous and categorical moderator variable.

Thanks all.